# Why there is a 302 status when my account and password are right?

Tags: login

I captured all the http requests and responses when to login my wordpress with account and password.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqQaR.jpg

Package number 22 is my http request when to login with account and password.

Package number 26 is my http response when to login with account and password.

Why there is a response ,package number 22,the status is 302?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packet number 22 is not a request, but an aswer to a request. [Status 302](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) just means the requested resource has been found and normally you are temporarily being redirected somewhere else. It doesn't say password is wrong or something liie that. Even on a successful login you are normally being redirected to the page you originally requested. In your case I guess the Response with 302 status code also redirects you to the page /wp/admin/. Thats why that page gets requested immediately after.